# Pasar 2 o mas varibles por metodo get

Tags: script

Estado
                
                
                    Estado

```
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-5">
            <select class="form-control" name="municipio" id="municipio">
              <option>Municipio </option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-5">
            <select class="form-control" name="parroquia" id="parroquia">
              <option>Parroquia</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

ESTE CODIGO RELLENA ESTADO Y MUNICIPIO MEDIANTE EL ARCHIVO DIRECIONES.JS

```
$(document).ready(
    function()
{
    cargar_estados();
    $("#estados").change(function(){cargar_municipio();});
    $("#municipio").change(function(){cargar_parroquia();});
    //$("#estados").change(function(){cargar_parroquia();});
    $("#municipio").attr("disabled",true);
    $("#parroquia").attr("disabled",true);
});

function cargar_estados()
{
    $.get("../../otros/cargar-estados.php", 
        function(resultado){
            if(resultado == false)
            {
                alert("Error al cargar Estado");
            }
            else
            {
                $('#estados').append(resultado);           
            }
        }); 
}

function cargar_municipio()
{
    var id_est = $("#estados").val();
    $.get("../../otros/cargar-municipio.php", { id_est:id_est },
        function(resultado)
        {
            //alert(id_est);
            if(resultado == false)
            {
                alert("Error al cargar Municipio");
            }
            else
            {
                $("#municipio").attr("disabled",false);
                document.getElementById("municipio").options.length=1;
                $('#municipio').append(resultado);         
            }
        }

    ); 
}
```

LA IDEA ES PASAR LAS VARIABLES #estado #municipio A LA FUNCION PARROQUIA PARA LUEGO PODER HACER EL SQL NECESARIO

```
<SCRIPT>
function cargar_parroquia()
{
    var id_est = $("#estado").val();
    var id_mun = $("#municipio").val();
    alert(id_est);
    /*$.get("../../otros/cargar-parroquia.php",{id_mun:id_mun}+{ id_est: id_est},
      function(resultado)
        {
            //alert(id_mun);
            //alert(id_est);
        if(resultado == false)
        {
            alert("Error al Cargar parroquia");
        }
        else
        {
            $("#parroquia").attr("disabled",false);
            document.getElementById("parroquia").options.length=1;
            $('#parroquia').append(resultado);         
        }
    });  */
}
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Tu pregunta se podría contestar: **poniendo esta línea así: `$.get("../../otros/cargar-parroquia.php",{id_mun:id_mun, id_est: id_est}`**. Aunque algunos aspectos del código se pueden mejorar. Todo lo que ocurre después de enviar el `get` (lo que tienes comentado)  es extraño, pero no se puede dar una respuesta adecuada que corrija ese código porque no es lo que preguntas y porque tampoco se sabe lo que ocurre en `cargar-parroquia.php`, qué tipo de dato devuelve, cómo lo devuelve, qué pasa si hay error, o si no encuentra registros.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando es un **GET** los parametros deberian enviarse en el *query string* (URL)

`$.get("../../otros/cargar-parroquia.php?id_mun="+id_mun+"&id_est="+id_est,...`

Answer (score 0):

Te propongo una solución basada en lo siguiente:

- Uso del método [`$getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/), porque será mucho más fácil recuperar los datos que responda el servidor. Ahora bien, el servidor deberá responder única y exclusivamente un objeto JSON válido, el cual leeremos en el `done` de la petición.
- Uso de código actualizado. Después de jQuery 3, `document.ready` es considerado obsoleto. Se recomienda el uso de `function`. Tendría un bloque así:

  ```
  $(function() {

      /*Aquí dentro todas las funciones*/

  });
  ```
- Para las peticiones al servidor, conviene implementar al menos un método `done` y otro `fail`, para informar de posibles errores.
- Trabajaremos con variables, para escribir un código más limpio y legible

### jQuery

```
$(function() {

    /*Aquí deberían ir todas tus funciones*/

    function cargar_parroquia(){

        var id_est = $('#estado').val();
        var id_mun = $('#municipio').val();
        var data={id_est: id_est, id_mun: id_mun};
        var url='../../otros/cargar-parroquia.php';

        var xhrGet = $.getJSON(url, data);

        xhrGet.done(function(datos) {
            if(datos.error){
                alert('Hubo un error en el servidor: '+datos.error);
            }else{
                /*Prueba*/
                console.log(datos);

                /*
                    *Leemos la respuesta accediendo en un bulce each por nombres de clave
                    *así podemos por ejemplo llenar las option de un select
                    *una tabla, un formulario, o lo que queramos
                    *y añadirlo a algun elemento del DOM
                */
                $.each(datos, function (k, v) {
                    console.log(v.id_mun);
                    console.log(v.municipio);
                });

            }
        });

        xhrGet.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert('Hubo un error: ' + textStatus);
        });
    }

});
```

---

### PHP

```
if( isset($_GET['id_est']) && isset($_GET['id_mun']) ) {    
    /*
        *Aquí lanzas la consulta y almacenas los resultados en un array
        *usando uno de los métodos fetch
        *vamos a suponer que esa variable se llama $arrResultado
        *y tendrá algo así más o menos
    */

    $arrResultado=array(array('id_mun'=>1,'municipio'=>'Municipio 1'), array('id_mun'=>2,'municipio'=>'Municipio 2'));

}else{

    /*Si hay error, creamos un array con la clave "error"*/
    $arrResultado=array('error'=>'Hubo un error: No se pasaron los parámetros en el GET');

}
/*Imprimimos el resultado, cualquiera que sea*/
header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8');
print_r(json_encode($arrResultado));
```

**NOTA IMPORTANTE:** Generalmente, cuando construyes un array de un conjunto de resultados de la base de datos, te crea en realidad un array JSON parecido a este:

```
[{
    "id_mun": 1,
    "municipio": "Municipio 1"
}, {
    "id_mun": 2,
    "municipio": "Municipio 2"
}]
```

La eventual lectura en el `done` no se hace como un objeto JSON, primero tienes que acceder al array, y luego al objeto JSON que está dentro.

Espero te sea de ayuda. Si tienes dudas en algo, puedes preguntar en comentarios.